# Auth0 mysql connection error using php

Tags: php, mysql, auth0

I am trying to connect my custom mysql database to Auth0.But i am getting the following error

> [Error] ECONNREFUSED - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

my code is,

```
function create (user, callback) {
  var connection = mysql({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'db_user',
    password : 'db_password',
    database : 'db_name'
  });

  connection.connect();

  var query = "INSERT INTO users SET ?";

  var insert = { 
    password: bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, 10),
    email:    user.email
  };

  connection.query(query, insert, function (err, results) {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    if (results.length === 0) return callback();

    callback(null);

  });

}
```

Comment: Is your mysql Server running and listen on localhost?

Comment: mysql server is running.Using localhost i can connect to database using php script.

Answer (score 0):

The script runs on Auth0 servers, so `localhost` would be auth0 itself. You need to use a network address that is reachable from Auth0 servers.

You can check [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) for bridging your own dev server with a cloud service (like Auth0).

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because Auth0 (Where the script runs) cannot reach your DB server. When the script runs Auth0 goes to localhost, in this case, the same Auth0, hence your connection is refused.  You will have to:

- bridge your connection with [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) as [Eugenio Pace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/349524/eugenio-pace) said, exposing your DB to the internet (thus making it visible to Auth0)
- And change the var connection attributes accordingly. (the server url and the user creds)

You can also check Auth0 documentation [here](https://auth0.com/docs/)